# Utilizo C# y las librerías cAlgo para un BOT Algorítmico. Quiero saber las posiciones BUY y SELL abiertas y el PNL para saber ganancias y pérdidas

Tags: c#

Necesito ayuda. Estoy desarrollando un BOT Algorítmico en C# y con las librerías que me ofrece la plataforma Ctrader, lo compilo en el apartado Automate y no me da errores de compilación, pero tampoco los resultados que quiero. He pedido ayuda al chatGPT OpenAI y me ha tenido todo el día dándome pruebas y error hasta aburrirme. Al final le he pedido que me de direcciones de paginas o foros donde pudieran ayudarme y me ha dado esta pagina. Espero ayuda. Gracias anticipadas. Facilito el código que compila bien y que funciona pero no me da los resultados esperados. Lo que quiero es saber las posiciones que tengo abiertas en ese momento y si están en perdidas o ganancias y saber cuales tengo que cerrar. Ya se que puedo hacerlas manualmente, pero yo quiero que lo haga automáticamente el BOT sino para que lo quiero. Y también cuando le doy la orden  Open(TradeType.Buy,"etiqueta"); me compruebe antes de abrir esa posición si ya hay abierta posición igual y que no haga nada, pero si la que está abierta en vez de Buy es Sell que la cierre antes de abrir el Buy.

//--- Codigo funcionando sin errores de compilación pero sin resultados correctos

```
      protected override void OnStart()
    {
     
     //--- Abro dos posiciones al inicio
     Open(TradeType.Buy,"xTicks");
     Open(TradeType.Sell,"xTicks");
     
     }
     

    protected override void OnTick()
    {
        // Me Suscríbeto al evento OnTick para obtener información actualizada en cada tick
        ++Tick;

        // Llamo a la función para obtener información sobre las posiciones abiertas
        // 
        GetOpenPositionsInfo();
    }

    private void GetOpenPositionsInfo()
    {
        // Obtén la lista de todas las posiciones abiertas
        var positions = Positions.FindAll("xTicks");

        // Itera sobre cada posición y muestra la información
        
        if (positions.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var position in positions)
            {
                Print($"Tipo: {position.TradeType}, " +
                    $"Símbolo: {position.SymbolName}, " +
                    $"Volumen: {position.VolumeInUnits}, " +
                    $"Precio de entrada: {position.EntryPrice}, " +
                    $"Ganancia/Pérdida: {position.NetProfit}");
            }
        
        }else{
                   Print("No hay posiciones abiertas que coincidan con los criterios.");
             }
    }

    // Maneja el evento OnTick si necesitas obtener información en cada tick
    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Llama a la función para obtener información sobre las posiciones abiertas en cada tick
        GetOpenPositionsInfo();
        
        Print("Obteniendo información sobre posiciones abiertas...");   
        
    }
    
    // El BOT abre las dos posiciones, pero cuando lo pongo en marcha funciona perfecto
    // pero solo me va escribiendo: Mo hay posiciones abiertas---
    
} // Cierre Namespace
```

}     // Cierre Robot